# How do I set the default size of /dev/shm?

Tags: lubuntu, tmpfs

I'd like to change the default size of /dev/shm in Lubuntu 11.10 (also known as /run/shm now, I guess).

It doesn't seem to appear in my fstab:

```
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=66ac63f0-45fa-4766-9d20-7c56bcd0460d /               ext3    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
UUID=227f1b29-5d04-4c28-9c9c-ea70b1726434 /home           ext3    noatime         0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
#UUID=9e13b7cc-1f75-4b4e-9e79-c0f7368de353 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0

tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noexec,nosuid 0 0
tmpfs /var/tmp tmpfs defaults,noexec,nosuid 0 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting a `/dev/shm` line in the `fstab` file to override the default settings:

```
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults,noexec,nosuid,size=100M 0 0
```

If that doesn't work, you can try remounting it after it's been mounted at boot, for example by putting this line into the `/etc/rc.local` file

```
mount -o remount,size=100M /run/shm
```

Comment: The remounting works. The `fstab` suggestion does not. We need something better...

Comment: Leastwise, this doesn't work in 11.10: see comments [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/917464).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/dev/shm`?

Comment: Mine is filling up with pulse-shm-##### files and I need to know why I should allow it to do it at all.  Certainly I don't want my SSD filling up with temp files at all.  The whole system is on a 160 SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary increase `tmpfs` filesystem

1) Open `/etc/fstab` with vi or any text editor of your choice,

2) Locate the line of `/dev/shm` and use the `tmpfs size` option to specify your expected size,
 - **e.g. 512MB:**

```
tmpfs      /dev/shm      tmpfs   defaults,size=512m   0   0
```

**e.g. 2GB:**

```
tmpfs      /dev/shm      tmpfs   defaults,size=2g   0   0
mount -o remount /dev/shm
```

Comment: **It doesn't seem to appear in my fstab**